# Permission denied for files to memory

Tags: python, image, directory

I am looking to create a compressed `numpy` array using pictures from my file `train2014` I'm getting an error where it says I don't have permission to access the file. Here is my code:

```
# dataset path
path = 'train2014/'
# load dataset
[src_images, tar_images] = load_images(path)
```

Here is the error provided:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'train2014/train2014'
```

Comment: Run your program with sudo? use `sudo chown -R $(whoami) train2014`?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, you are not able to access the file while it is already open by another program.

If this is not the case, you simply need to grant your user sufficient permissions in order to be able to read (or write) to the file.

Comment: How would I do that? I am using Windows 10

Comment: @MattB. `icacls "D:\path\to\train2014\" /grant Matt:(OI)(CI)F /T` this command is going to give _full control_ for user _Matt_